# System normalizer of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $\Sigma$ is a Hall system of a group $G$, the subgroup $N_G(\Sigma) = \{g\in G | H = H^g \;\text{for all} \;H\in \Sigma \}$ is called the normalizer of $\Sigma$

Suppose that $G$ is a finite soluble group. Let $\{p_1,\ldots,p_k \}$ be the set of prime divisors of $|G|$ and $K = \{ G, Q_1, Q_2,\ldots, Q_k\}$ be the set of Hall $p_i'$-subgroups

Show that $N_G(\Sigma) = N_G(K) := \displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}
N_G(Q_i)$

My approach: I have shown that $K$ is contained in $\Sigma$ hence $N_G(K) \leq N_G(\Sigma)$

For the other inclusion, let $g\in N_G(\Sigma)$ then $H = H^g$ for all $H\in \Sigma$. Thus $g\in N_G(H)$ for all $H\in \Sigma$.

I know each $H \in \Sigma$ is of the form $H = \bigcap Q$ for some $Q_i$'s from $K$

Comment: Surely $K$ contained in $\Sigma$ gives $N_G(\Sigma) \le N_G(K)$ rather than the other way round. So you need to prove $N_G(K) \le N_G(\Sigma)$, but that follows from the fact that all elements of $\Sigma$ are intersections of elements from $K$.

Comment: I understand how the second inclusion follows. I'm not sure how $K \subset \Sigma$ implies $N_G(\Sigma) \subset N_G(K)$

Comment: $g \in N_G(\Sigma) \Rightarrow H^g=H \,\forall H \in \Sigma \Rightarrow H^g=H\, \forall H \in K \Rightarrow g \in N_G(K)$.